# bxslider wont work correctly

Tags: jquery, css

Been having a problem on getting [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/) to work. I went wrong I imagine around the last step--in calling the bxSlider. Everything is linked from the same folder.

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fq23j3sr/1/)**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<!-- jQuery library (served from Google) -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider Javascript file -->
<script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
<!-- bxSlider CSS file -->

<link href="jquery.bxslider.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript">
  jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        jQuery('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 200,
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 3,
            slideMargin: 10
      });
  });    
</script>
</head>

<body>
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="../Luke Portfolio 2 - rough_idea/factormedia.co.za/images/fader1.png" /></li>
  <li><img src="../Luke Portfolio 2 - rough_idea/factormedia.co.za/images/fader2.png" /></li>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `jQuery 1.8.3`.

There were a few problems with your code. Here's the working fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/fq23j3sr/7/

In your JS, you were trying to initialize the `bxSlider()` function, **BEFORE** you actually loaded the plugin you were trying to reference. Simply moving:

```
// JavaScript Document
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
});
```

Below the plugin code will solve the issue of the undefined function error.

Hope this helps.

EDIT:
**auto start** - as asked in the comments:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.wrapper').bxSlider({
        'auto' : true,
        'autoStart' : true
    });
});
```

Comment: @isherwood yeah, it appears it does. I'll adjust my answer.

Comment: @isherwood the init script was actually happening twice in OPs original fiddle - top of the JS file and in the HTML window - which won't render that JS. OP was also not loading jQuery at all in the fiddle settings.

Comment: Ok. I wasn't looking at the fiddle, having assumed the posted code to be more accurate.

Comment: perfect. Seems just by changing my html caller, and library to a higher version it did what i needed!

Comment: is there any way to adjust the jquery to make it change picture over time? I been looking into that while looking for a solution

Comment: Yeah, you can set an option for `auto : true,` and that should work. Check out the documentation at http://bxslider.com/options and find `auto`, `pause` and `autoStar`t.

Comment: i added what the documentation said, expcept it gives me an error when I use 

$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  auto: true,
  autoControls: true
});

Comment: @factordog updated the answer with a new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/fq23j3sr/7/ and the options.

Answer (score 1):

Your fiddle has a little messed up, so i created my own. Here is a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jbLm2spv/
I think the problem in your code is that you use jQuery 1.8.2, which might be too old for bxSlider. Use a newer jQuery version, like 2.1.3 instead.

The html markup:

```
<ul class="bxslider">
  <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&bg=000&txtclr=fff&txt=500%C3%97300&w=500&h=300" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&bg=ccc&txtclr=fff&txt=500%C3%97300&w=500&h=300" /></li>
    <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&bg=000&txtclr=fff&txt=500%C3%97300&w=500&h=300" /></li>
  <li><img src="https://placeholdit.imgix.net/~text?txtsize=47&bg=ccc&txtclr=fff&txt=500%C3%97300&w=500&h=300" /></li>
</ul>
```

The js:

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
            slideWidth: 200,
            minSlides: 2,
            maxSlides: 3,
            slideMargin: 10
});
```

Comment: going to seem like a dumb question. but where would i find the relevant link for the ajax library for 2.1.3.....also if the tutorial on the site gave the 1.8.2 version surely it should work?

Comment: also when I changed it to 2.1.3 on my fiddle I had, seemed to work actually. Problem comes in where i dont know how to rectify the problem.

Comment: You can download it from here: http://jquery.com/download/. Well, in my fiddle I tried it with jquery 2.1.3 and it works. Here's the minified version, the latest, 2.1.4: http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js

Comment: is there no way to rather instead of downloading access the library like the did in the tutorial with <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: You can just include this link as a resource: https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js if you want, it's not necesary to download it, but downloading it would be a safer way if the jquery cdn will be down some time.

Comment: I downloaded and linked <script src="jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script> but to no avail :/

Comment: thanks for your help with getting my understanding of library sorted. Someone found the answer, seems the order of my caller as well as u stated the correct librabry version was needed.

Answer (score 1):

Do you see any errors in your console? The way you are enqueuing bxslider assumes that you have the file downloaded, and in the same directory as your index.html:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
// This assumes you jquery.bxslider.min.js is in the same folder as the file that loads this page. 
<script src="jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

Edit:

Okay, sounds like you have a few errors to fix. The first, being jQuery not being defined. You need to add http to the beginning of your jQuery path, or else it is looking at the file:// protocol, which means it is looking locally on your own machine, as opposed to the URL that is hosting the jQuery library you are trying to load:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

That should solve your "$ is not defined" error.

Secondly, you need to download the jquery.bxslider.min.js file, and put it in the appropriate directory. The way you have it now, it is looking in the same directory as the file that loads your page (index.html, for example). You can either put it there, or you can create a new directory (for better organization), and put it there. I would recommend creating a folder called "js".

To download it, you can just copy the text from this link:

https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stevenwanderski/bxslider-4/master/dist/jquery.bxslider.min.js

and save it into a file called jquery.bxslider.min.js, either on the same level as your index.html, or in a js folder, and update your script src accordingly:

```
<script src="js/jquery.bxslider.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
jquery.bxslider.min.js:10 Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
slider.html:14 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined                       

are the 3 errors

Answer (score 1):

There were several issues that were fundamental to the operation of your Fiddle. Here's a [**fork**](https://jsfiddle.net/zer00ne/hh0szym3/) of the original.

- The urls to the images were relative not absolute. The urls also had spaces in them as well.

  - **WRONG**
    <del>`../Luke Portfolio 2 - rough_idea/factormedia.co.za/images/fader1.png`</del>
  - **CORRECT**
    `http://www.example.com/Luke%20Portfolio%202%20-%20rough_idea/factormedia.co.za/images/fader1.png`
- When using jsFiddle, you should use the rightside panel to enter urls to external files.

  - `jquery.bxslider.min.js`, and `jquery.bxslider.css` should be uploaded to your own website or you should use a [CDN](http://www.jsdelivr.com). Then you need to use the url instead of pasting the code in the editing panels.

`

Comment: its just loading a blank page

Comment: @factordog My bad, sorry, it's fixed now.